# how to force bootstrap accordion menu to collapse when a child li is clicked

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, menu, accordion

i have a bootstrap 3.2 accordion menu with the following markup

```
<div class="accordion">
  <div class="accordion-group">
    <div class="accordion-heading"> <a class="accordion-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseFour">Cleaning and Painting</a> </div>
    <div class="accordion-body collapse" id="collapseFour">
      <div class="accordion-inner">
        <ul class="links">
          <li class="l1 open"><a href="air-compressor.html">Air Compressor</a>
          <li class="l2"><a href="paint-sprayer.html">Paint Sprayer</a>
          <li class="lL"><a href="pressure-cleaner.html">Pressure Cleaner</a>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

When a child `<li>` is clicked, in this case, Air Compressor, it sets the `<li>` class to open.  Now i need to force the menu to collapse (ie to open) and the markup needs to look like this:

```
<div class="accordion">
  <div class="accordion-group">
    <div class="accordion-heading"> <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseFour">Cleaning and Painting</a> </div>
    <div class="accordion-body collapse in" id="collapseFour" >
      <div class="accordion-inner">
        <ul class="links">
          <li class="l1 open"> <a href="air-compressor,48.html">Air Compressor</a> </li>
          <li class="l2"> <a href="paint-sprayer,49.html">Paint Sprayer</a> </li>
          <li class="lL"> <a href="pressure-cleaner,50.html">Pressure Cleaner</a> </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

I am using the following jQuery to add the "open" class to the child `<li>` that has been clicked.

```
(function($){ 
            $(document).ready(function(){
            var pathname = window.location.pathname,
            page = pathname.split(/[/ ]+/).pop(),
            menuItems = $('.accordion-inner .links a');
            menuItems.each(function(){
            var mi = $(this),
            miHrefs = mi.attr("href"),
            miParents = mi.parents('li');
            if(page == miHrefs) {
            miParents.addClass("open").siblings().removeClass('open');
            }
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

and I need to be able to collapse the DIV to which it belongs to so that the user know which section they are viewing. Hope I am making sense.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Consider following jquery code:

```
$('.links li a').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.accordion .in').collapse('hide');
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://fiddle.jshell.net/7vRV9/87/)

Comment: Thanks Manwal. This is not doing what i need. I need the menu to collapse (open) if a child li class is set to open <li class="open">, there is no click action involved.

Comment: And what is the menu??